# How to programmatically import CSS files from node_modules in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am working on a website where I need to toggle between dark mode and light mode. Both mode uses different CSS files from node_modules (from a package). Now, how can we dynamically import and use CSS files from node_modules?

Regular import `import cssfile from 'package-name/path/to/cssfile'` works however, assigning link href to `'package-name/path/to/cssfile'` gives Not Found error.

CSS files are working when imported using import statement. But, the requirement is to import the files based on toggle.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot proceed that way as node_modules package are not accessible directly on runtime.

On your project, you have to declare 2 css such like "dark.css" and "light.css"

On `dark.css` you can used @import (or whatever you want depending if you are on sass, less, etc.) to import css from node_modules :
`@import '~package-name/path/to/cssfile_dark'`
You have to do the same for light.css

That way, when building your project, you will have 2 CSS generated (check your conf to add them both), dark.css and light.css will be accessible on runtime, meaning using href link.

Best,

EL

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not an issue with loading css dynamically.

For a fundamental solution, dark mode must be applied in a different way.

- Option 1: Toggle `<link />` tag dynamically (not recommended, what you tried).

  - Not recommended because of potential issue with style conflict or delayed styles.
  - To do this, you must first copy the CSS from node_modules to the public directory or follow [Errol Lebron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23118321/errol-lebron)'s way (may require build settings for it).
- Option 2: Toggle classes or attributes for identify dark mode on tags such as `<html>` or `<body>`.

  - For example: see [tailwindcss - 'class' strategy](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#toggling-dark-mode-manually)
  - This may require editing your CSS entirely. (PostCSS makes it trivial.)